# Why am I getting error 404 in my django project when everything seems correct?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I have two apps in my Django project:**basket** and **store**. In root url files I configured the **urls.py** like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('store.urls', namespace='store')),
    path('basket/', include('basket.urls', namespace='basket')),
```

**store/urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'store'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.all_products, name='all_products'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    path('category/<slug:category_slug>/',
         views.category_list, name='category_list')
]
```

**basket/urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'basket'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.basket_summary, name='basket_summary'),
    path('add/', views.basket_add, name='basket_add'),
]
```

I am getting an error:
**Page not found(404)**

**Request Method:GET**

**Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/basket/**

**Raised by:store.views.product_detail**

this is my **store/views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .models import *

def product_detail(request, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug, in_stock=True)
    context = {
        'product': product,
    }

    return render(request, 'store/products/detail.html', context)
```

please help me solve this problem i've been stuck on this for a long time.

Comment: you are using get_object_or_404 as query params that is the reason.

Comment: get_object_or_404 is basically if it does not get query set it will return you with 404 error basically it is get or give 404 hope you got clear.

Comment: @daneilJames I don't quite get it. You are saying that if it doesn't contain data I will get 404?

Comment: basically you are querying to get certain query i.e product model that have in_stock = True and i am assuming you have set slug as unique. Now when you are using get_object_or_404 if there is slug and stock =True it will give you  some query in return in your context otherwise you will be given 404 error.

Comment: @daneilJames ooohh okay thanks, now it's clear. thanks.

Comment: does the ans below satisfies your requirement you can accept the ans.

Comment: @daneilJames yeah I'm applying it to my code but im getting a NameError

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231470/discussion-between-daneil-james-and-myrodis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way if you want to avoid 404 error:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .models import *

    def product_detail(request, slug):
        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug, in_stock=True)
            context = {
                'product': product,
            }
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError('Product Does not exist ')
    
        return render(request, 'store/products/detail.html', context

)
```